# ESS[SAS] F3 button and "File Mode Specification error: (void-variable ess-ac-sources)"

Tags: emacs, sas, key-bindings, ess

I have been searching for an answer/solution to this problem. I am not sure how it happened or what I did (if anything), but when I hit F3 to run a batch file for SAS in ESS[SAS] mode, it doesn't work. I have been using it all day and it suddenly just doesn't work anymore... If I call `M-x ess-sas-global-unix-keys` while in `SAS-mode` I can use the F3-F6 buttons, but having `(setq ess-sas-global-unix-keys t)` in my `init.d` file upon opening a `.sas` file doesn't bind F3-F6 to the necessary commands.

Also, when I now open a `.sas` file, I get the message "File mode specification error: (void-variable ess-ac-sources)" and the F3-F6 key-bindings no longer work in `SAS-mode`.

I checked to make sure I have everything up-to-date (everything appears to be: i.e. auto-complete, ess), I debugged using `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, but I can't find what is wrong (not that I would necessarily know what I am looking for, I am still new to Emacs).

In my init.el file, the only reference I have to ESS is the `ess-sas-global-unix-keys`. I feel like the specification error is having an effect on the ESS[SAS] keybindings, but I don't know how to fix it. I am also at a loss as to why it just started happening, even though I had been using it all day long. What can I do?

**EDIT:**

As per the comments, I will be sending an email to the ESS-help mailing list as well as listing out the backtrace list from the `debug-on-error`.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable ess-ac-sources)
  ess-load-extras()
  ess-mode(((ess-local-customize-alist quote SAS-customize-alist) (ess-language . "SAS") (ess-dialect . "SAS") (ess-mode-editing-alist . SAS-editing-alist) (ess-mode-syntax-table . SAS-syntax-table) (inferior-ess-program . inferior-SAS-program-name) (ess-help-sec-regex . "^[A-Z. ---]+:$") (ess-help-sec-keys-alist . " ") (ess-object-name-db-file . "ess-sas-namedb.el") (inferior-ess-objects-command . "objects(%d)") (inferior-ess-help-command . "help(\"%s\",pager=\"cat\",window=F)\n") (inferior-ess-exit-command . "endsas;\n") (ess-loop-timeout . 500000) (inferior-ess-primary-prompt . "^") (inferior-ess-secondary-prompt . "^") (comint-use-prompt-regexp . t) (inferior-ess-start-file) (inferior-ess-start-args . inferior-SAS-args-temp) (inferior-ess-font-lock-defaults . SAS-mode-font-lock-defaults)) nil)
  SAS-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(SAS-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer cleaning-0yr.sas> "~/Documents/datasets/PROMISE/data/scripts/cleaning-0yr.sas" nil nil "~/Documents/datasets/PROMISE/data/scripts/cleaning-0yr.sas" (5673145 2049))
  find-file-noselect("~/Documents/datasets/PROMISE/data/scripts/cleaning-0yr.sas" nil nil t)
  find-file("~/Documents/datasets/PROMISE/data/scripts/cleaning-0yr.sas" t)
  call-interactively(find-file nil nil)
```

Comment: Please send a mail to ess help [mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/ess-help) and give a description of the workflow and the version of ESS and emacs that you are using. You will get more help there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ESS, but I can tell what the error means: `ess-ac-sources` is a variable which contains a special list crafted for `auto-complete` library; this library will then use it to decide how to complete words in the file. What could possibly happen? - the names for sources usually follow a different pattern. It would've normally been `ac-sources-ess`. Is it possibly that this is just a typo in the source code? Try `M-: (setq debug-on-error t)`, rerun the offending code and tell us what function is causing the problem.

Comment: @wvxvw The offending code is `ess-load-extras()`

Comment: You probably want to add the stack trace to the question. I'm just really not familiar with this package, but perhaps someone who is will be able to reply better.

Comment: I've looked here: https://svn.r-project.org/ESS/trunk/lisp/ess.el and it just seems to be a bug, because neither `auto-complete` nor `ess` itself define this variable. So I'd report it as a bug to the maintainer, and add `(defvar ess-ac-sources nil)` to the `.emacs` file, until it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks, @wvxvw. I have sent a message to the ESS-help list and they responded that it is indeed undefined and that they will fix it. I included your suggested code into the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened since I had tried this before, but today I again replaced `(setq ess-sas-global-unix-keys t)` with simply `(ess-sas-global-unix-keys)` (at the suggestion from the ESS-help mailing list) and the F3-F6 buttons now work in ESS[SAS] mode. I did get an update to emacs this morning, so that may have contributed to the fix. I still get the "File mode specification error..." though.

**EDIT**

As per @wvxvw comment, including `(defvar ess-ac-sources nil)` into the init.el (or .emacs) file prevented the "File mode..." error from occurring.